# Deadlock caused by point-to-point communication in MPI, using a loop to send from master to children

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm attempting to solve a homework problem to debug the following unit test.

Basically the master process generates random integers and sends them to child processes to check for primality, the result is communicated back to the master process, and the algorithm ends.

I know that the loops should be replaced with collective communication, however that is a different part of the question. I want to understand why this code I have here is causing deadlock.

From reading other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754224/mpi-send-and-receive-deadlock), I know that the number of sends/receives should match each other. However I don't see how this isn't the case in my code.

The current behaviour is that a prime is found, sent back to the master process, at which point the program just hangs - until it's canceled manually using ctrl-C.

I understand that this isn't the idiomatic way of solving this problem, but would really like to know exactly where the bug is in this approach.

thanks!

```
TEST_CASE("3a - Finding prime numbers", "[MPI]" )
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Random number generation
    std::minstd_rand generator;
    unsigned min(2342), max(12342340);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(min, max);

    // candidates too big, one of the size values is the master node
    std::vector<unsigned> candidates(size - 1);

    // Main loop continues until a prime is found
    int found_prime(0);
    while (found_prime == 0) {


        if (rank == 0) {

            // Create some candidate numbers for each process to test
            std::generate(candidates.begin(), candidates.end(),
                          [&]() { return distribution(generator); });

            // Send one to each worker
            for (int worker(1); worker < size; ++worker) {
                int rc = MPI_Ssend(&candidates[worker - 1], 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
                                   worker, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                REQUIRE(rc == MPI_SUCCESS);
            }

            // Receive whether it was prime
            for (int worker(1); worker < size; ++worker) {
                unsigned result;
                int rc = MPI_Recv(&result, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, worker, 0,
                                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                REQUIRE(rc == MPI_SUCCESS);
                if (result == 1) {
                    found_prime = candidates[worker - 1];
                    std::cout << "Worker " << worker << " found prime "
                              << found_prime << std::endl;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Receive the candidate to check
            unsigned candidate;
            int rc = MPI_Recv(&candidate, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                              MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            REQUIRE(rc == MPI_SUCCESS);
            // Do the check
            unsigned is_prime = mp::IsPrime(candidate) ? 1 : 0;
            // Return the result
            rc = MPI_Ssend(&is_prime, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            REQUIRE(rc == MPI_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Finished" << rank << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about MPI, but in your code, if `rank != 0`, the while loop can never be exited because `found_prime` is never set in the `else` branch (and `rank` is never changed too).

Edit:

As @DanielLangr said, the slaves will need a way to find out that there's no more work to come and exit (the loop).

Comment: In MPI, the rank indicates the process and therefore the else will always run as long as you have more than 1 process.

Comment: No, the loop has to be entered by all processes (ohterwise the number of sends/recvs wouldn't match). However, the loop for slaves never ends, that's correct. The problem is that other processes do not know when one of them finds a prime. However, the root knows, so you just need to send to slaves some special message. MPI tags are perfect for that.

Comment: Oh my gosh @DanielLangr thank you so much, I've been tearing my hair out over this for hours. :)

Comment: @skailasa You're welcome. You can find some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494108/580083.